# Not Able to Add contact in google Contacts using AuthSuB in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, contacts

My problem is that I am not able to add contacts in google. I am using asp.net 2008.Same thing when I am using with google calender it is saving without any problem. I am not sure wheather it is a token problem or something else so i decided to ask here.
Below is my code for adding Contacts

```
 protected void Create_Click()
    {

    GAuthSubRequestFactory authFactory_con = new GAuthSubRequestFactory("cp", "ContactApp");
    authFactory_con.Token = (String)Session["token"];
    ContactsService ser = new ContactsService(authFactory_con.ApplicationName);
    ser.RequestFactory = authFactory_con;               

    string str = "";



        ContactDetail contact = new ContactDetail
        {
            Name = NameTextBox.Text + " " + LastTextBox.Text,
            EmailAddress1 = primaryEmailTextBox.Text,
            EmailAddress2 = secondryEmailTextBox.Text,
            Phone = phoneTextBox.Text,
            Mobile = MobileTextBox.Text,
            Street = StreetTextBox.Text,
            City = CityTextBox.Text,
            Region = RegionTextBox.Text,
            PostCode = PostCodeTextBox.Text,
            Country = CountryTextBox.Text,
            Details = detailsTextBox.Text

        };

            GoogleContactService.AddContact(contact,ser);
            str = "<script>alert('Contact Added Sucessfully')</script>";

        Response.Write(str);   


}
```

Above function calls AddContact function of GoogleContactService. Below is the code for Add Contact Function

```
   public void AddContact(ContactDetail contact, ContactsService GContactService)
     {
    ContactEntry newEntry = new ContactEntry();

    newEntry.Title.Text = contact.Name;
    //newEntry.Name.FullName = contact.Name;  

    newEntry.Name = new Name();     
    newEntry.Name.FullName = contact.Name;

    EMail primaryEmail = new EMail(contact.EmailAddress1);
    primaryEmail.Primary = true;
    primaryEmail.Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsWork;
    newEntry.Emails.Add(primaryEmail);

    EMail secondaryEmail = new EMail(contact.EmailAddress2);
    secondaryEmail.Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsHome;
    newEntry.Emails.Add(secondaryEmail);

    PhoneNumber phoneNumber = new PhoneNumber(contact.Phone);
    phoneNumber.Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsHome ;
    newEntry.Phonenumbers.Add(phoneNumber);

    PhoneNumber phoneNumber_ = new PhoneNumber(contact.Mobile );
    phoneNumber_.Primary = true;
    phoneNumber_.Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsMobile ;
    newEntry.Phonenumbers.Add(phoneNumber_);

    newEntry.PostalAddresses.Add(new StructuredPostalAddress()
    {
        Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsWork,
        Primary = true,
        Street = contact.Street  ,
        City = contact.City  ,
        Region = contact.Region  ,
        Postcode = contact.PostCode  ,
        Country = contact.Country  ,
        FormattedAddress = contact.Street + " , " + contact.City + " , " + contact.Region + " , " + contact.PostCode + " , " + contact.Country,
    });      
    newEntry.Content.Content = contact.Details;
    Uri feedUri = new Uri(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("default"));

   // Uri feedUri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    ContactEntry createdEntry = (ContactEntry)GContactService.Insert(feedUri, newEntry);

}
```

I am getting token at page load

Below is the error getting when I am trying to add Contact.

GDataRequestException was unhandled by user code
Execution of request failed: https//www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got the solution for my problem. its a very silly mistake.

What I was doing that i was using multiscope token (for calender and contacts)
For getting multiscope token I was using below code

```
 string nextUrl = Request.Url.ToString();
 const string scope = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/%20http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/";
 const bool secure = false;
 const bool session = true;
 string authSubUrl = AuthSubUtil.getRequestUrl(nextUrl, scope, secure, session);
 Response.Redirect(authSubUrl);
```

From The above "const string scope" variable you have to remove %20 and give space.In google Api  documentation it is given as %20 but it dont work. You have to remove %20 and add space between them.Like below string.

```
 const string scope = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/ http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/";
```

By using %20 in the string you get only access to first service not second.Thats why stated error was coming.